# Something like autolayout or constraints

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I just started using SpriteBuilder and was wondering if something like “autolayout” (in a basic form) was possible for the apps? You see I have made this simple layout ( http://cl.ly/Szs3 ) containing a header (blue-ish) and body (red).

Now what I want is that the header has a fixed height (it has 100% percent width, so that goes wel) and the red block “fills” the rest of the screen. So when the device is a taller device more content at once can be shown.

Is this possible? And if so, how could I acchieve this.

Comment: not to my knowledge. I end up coding the 'relative offsets' from a base object for every other object as a function of device type and retina'ness ... but i'll be watching the answers on this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes there is such an option, yet the naming is a little bit different.**

I uploaded my example project to this GitHub Repo: https://github.com/MakeGamesWithUs/Spritebuilder-Simple-Autosizing

Your top container needs a static height, and a relative position and a Y Anchor Point of 1. This way the top container always has a size of 100 points and is always positioned at the top of the screen: 
[image]

Your bottom container needs a *height inset* of 100, this means your container will use the complete height of the parent container, except for 100 points at the top:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at:

- Auto Layout[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213665/4770877) Constraints
- [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)