# UIButton not showing the circle with "i" for .infoLight

Tags: swift, swift3, uibutton, programmatically-created

For some reason the iOS button standard circle with an "i" in it for .infoLight isn't showing when I run the function below to programmatically add a UIButton (and I do want to do this programmatically rather than in the interface builder) - I'm adding it to a UIPageViewController.  I do get a button in the lower left of the screen, and I've set it to .backgroundColor = .lightGray to verify it has been added to the subview & is working (image on the left, below). Any thoughts on the likely very basic thing that I'm missing?  Much thanks!

```
func configureAboutButton() {
    let aboutButtonHeight: CGFloat = 44
    let aboutButtonWidth: CGFloat = 44
    aboutButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
    aboutButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
    aboutButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - aboutButtonHeight, width: aboutButtonWidth, height: aboutButtonHeight))
    aboutButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    aboutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segueToAboutVC), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(aboutButton)
}
```

Curiously if I add this line just below where I set background color, the image on the right shows (otherwise I get the image on the left).

aboutButton.setTitle("X", for: .normal)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

After you create your button with `aboutButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight))` you create it again with `aboutButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - aboutButtonHeight, width: aboutButtonWidth, height: aboutButtonHeight))`. Thats why the info icon isn't showing.

### Solution

Just set the frame of your button via setting the frame property       `aboutButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - aboutButtonHeight, width: aboutButtonWidth, height: aboutButtonHeight)` and you can delete `aboutButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - aboutButtonHeight, width: aboutButtonWidth, height: aboutButtonHeight))`:

```
func configureAboutButton() {
  let aboutButtonHeight: CGFloat = 44
  let aboutButtonWidth: CGFloat = 44
  aboutButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
  aboutButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
  aboutButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - aboutButtonHeight, width: aboutButtonWidth, height: aboutButtonHeight)
  aboutButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
  aboutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segueToAboutVC), for: .touchUpInside)
  view.addSubview(aboutButton)
}
```

[image]

### Hint

A better solution would be to use one of the [auto layout options to set constraints programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html). In the version below I use **Layout Anchors** to set the constraints. Advantages of auto layout you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860483/5327882) for example.

```
func configureAboutButton() {
  aboutButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
  // need to set to false, to set the constraints programmatically
  aboutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  aboutButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
  aboutButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
  aboutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segueToAboutVC), for: .touchUpInside)
  view.addSubview(aboutButton)

  // set the constraints via Layout Anchors
  // x, y, w, h
  aboutButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
  aboutButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  aboutButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
  aboutButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: This was hugely helpful.  Thanks much!

Comment: Perfect, great that I could help you!